# how to set text to readonly Combo in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox, swt, jface

Normally if I want to set text to a Combo I can do the following: `combo.setText("text");`
It looks like that this approach does not work if my combo was initialized with SWT.READ_ONLY.

```
combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

It is neccessary to me to have a combo with fixed values. It is also important to use one of these values as default value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can provide a fixed array of values, set them as items in the `Combo` and select one of them by index.

Provide a constant value array in a related class:

```
private static final String[] YOUR_ENTRIES = { "Entry 1", "Entry 2", "Entry 3", "Entry 4" };
```

Then initialize the `Combo` like this:

```
// initialize it as read-only and drop-down
Combo readOnlyCombo = new Combo(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
// set the item array as the item source
readOnlyCombo.setItems(YOUR_ENTRIES);
// set the desired index to be selected as the default selection (index 0 is the first item)
readOnlyCombo.select(0);
```